# (Tangent Plane) Do Carmo Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces Ch.2.4 Prop.2

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

In proposition 2, given two regular surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ with parametrizations $\mathbf{x} : U_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow S_1$ and $\overline{\mathbf{x}} : U_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow S_2$ respectively. Also let $\varphi : V \subset S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ be a differentiable mapping of an open set of $S_1$ into $S_2$ with $p \in V$. Finally let $\alpha : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \rightarrow V$ be a curve with $\alpha(0) = p$, $\alpha'(0) =w \in T_p(S_1)$, where $T_p(S_1)$ is the tangent plane of $S_1$ at point $p$, and let $\beta = \varphi \circ \alpha$ such that $\beta(0) = \varphi(p)$. The proposition want to show that the map $d\varphi_p : T_p(S_1) \rightarrow T_{\varphi(p)}(S_2)$ defined by $d\varphi_p(w) = \beta'(0)$ is linear.

The problem is that in the proof, Carmo express $\varphi$ in 
$$\varphi(u, v) = (\varphi_1(u, v), \varphi_2(u, v)).$$
I understand that we can express vectors in $T_p(S_1) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ using the basis $\{\mathbf{x}_u(q), \mathbf{x}_v(q)\}$, where $\mathbf{x}(q) = p$, because $T_p(S_1)$ is of dimension 2. But isn't $S_2$ not necessarily of dimension 2? How can we use only two tuples to describe a 3 dimensional vector?

Comment: Here is a good resource. It uses the basis given by the parametrizations. Thus the 'coordinates' of the tangents are 2-dimensional. https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Courses/443-2013/differentials.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He's being sloppy with notation, I guess. If $\varphi$ is really a map on (a portion of) $S_1$ to $S_2$, then what he's writing is $\overline{\mathbf x}{}^{-1} \circ \varphi\circ \mathbf x$, mapping $(u,v)$ coordinates on $S_1$ to $(u',v')$ coordinates on $S_2$. This is how we work with such maps if we wish to compute things.

Comment: But according to the definition, we're about to compute $\beta'(0)$ where $\beta = \phi \circ \alpha$. The $\beta$ is mapping $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. How is that related to your comments?

Comment: @Stack_Underflow No, $\beta$ is mapping $\Bbb R$ to $S_2$, so $\beta'(0)$ is an element of $T_{\varphi(p)}S_2$. We are reducing this to a question of understanding a linear map from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Thanks, I roughly got the point. To make it more precise, could you give some more detail in your own answer if you like to?