# Coordinate maps applied to curves in the differential geometry of surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces, submanifold

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be a surface and $x:U \to V$ be a chart of $S$, i.e., $U$ is an open subset of $S$, $V$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $x$ is onto and one-to-one and $x^{-1}:V \to U$ is $C^{\infty}$.

Let $\gamma$ and $\tau$ be curves from an open interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ to $U$ with $\gamma(0)=\tau(0)$ and $\gamma'(0)=\tau'(0)$. Is it true that $(x \circ \gamma)'(0)=(x \circ \tau)'(0)$? If so, what is the proof?

In my studies of basic differential geometry, I was confronted with the above question on several occasions but have no idea how to answer it. The main problem I have is that we cannot apply the chain rule to $(x \circ \gamma)'$ since it is not allowed to differentiate the map $x:U\to V$.

For people who know do Carmo's *Differential geometry of curves and surfaces* for example, Do Carmo seems to implicitly assume that the claim is true in his proof of Proposition 2, Section 2-4, Chapter 2. The proposition is about the differential of a smooth map between two surfaces. He defines the differnetial via curves representing a tangential vector and among other things, he shows that his definition is independent of the curve. The above claim seems to be one step in his proof but he doesn't explain why it holds.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It drives me nuts that DoCarmo writes his undergraduate geometry text treating surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$ as abstract differentiable manifolds. It is more maddening yet that he uses the same letter $\mathbf x$ both for a chart on $S$ and for a parametrization of $S$. The derivative $\alpha'(0)$ makes sense *only* because $S\subset\Bbb R^3$ and you differentiate $\alpha$ as a map to $\Bbb R^3$. In fact, the proof you refer to is working with parametrized surfaces, with the $\mathbf x$ mapping going in the other direction. He shows that the tangent plane, defined as the image of the derivative map of the parametrization, consists of all tangent vectors of curves. In this direction, the chain rule works fine. And, yes, DoCarmo uses the Inverse Function Theorem liberally when he needs it.

(For your amusement, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962602/tangent-plane-do-carmo-differential-geometry-of-curves-and-surfaces-ch-2-4-pro?rq=1) for an instance of DoCarmo's using the "usual" sloppy conventions that people do with abstract manifolds. This is in exactly the portion of the text you're reading, as it happens.)

So, can you edit your question to clarify where the situation you have set up actually shows up in DoCarmo?

Comment: As I said, it occurs in the proof in proposition 2, section 2-4, chapter 2. But this is not the main part of my question. It should only serve as an example for people who know the book. (There are also other situations where I was wondering about my question.) The main question about the composition $(x \circ \gamma)'$ and in the situation I described, the chain rule doesn't work (or do not see how it should work).

Comment: I do not find what you're talking about anywhere in DoCarmo's treatment. As I said, what does $\alpha'(0)$ even mean? We do not know how to differentiate a map to the surface $S$. Only because the surface sits in $\Bbb R^3$ does this even make sense. Ordinarily, when we work with abstract manifolds, we define $\alpha'(0)$ only by composing $\alpha$  with a chart in the first place. What DoCarmo is doing is different from what you think: He's defining $\alpha$ to be $\mathbf x\circ \bar\alpha$ for some smooth mapping $\bar\alpha$ to $V$. Here $\mathbf x$ is a parametrization, not a chart.

Comment: In my setting, $x \circ \gamma : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. So it should be ok to talk about  $(x \circ \gamma)'(0)$. It is just a map from an interval to $\mathbb{R}^2$. We can differentiate it in the sense of "classical" calculus.

Comment: So prove that for any chart $x$, the inverse mapping $x^{-1}$ is a parametrization and then consider $x^{-1}\circ(x\circ\alpha)$, as I suggested.

Comment: Concerning the reference in DoCarmo: It is the part where he expresses $\beta'(0)$ as a linear combination with coefficients $u'(0), v'(0)$. Then he says $\beta'$ only depends on $u'(0), v'(0)$ and that "$\beta'(0)$ is therefore independent of $\alpha$". I don't see why it is "therefore" independent of $\alpha$.

Comment: This is the usual chain rule proof with the *parametrization*. He is considering $\alpha$ (as I already said) obtained by mapping from the parameter space, and all that is relevant is the tangent vector, not the particular curve. What you need to establish is that *any* curve is obtained in this manner (as I said above), and *that* in turn follows from my remark two comments up (about $x^{-1}$ being a parametrization).

Comment: Thanks. I think I see how the trick with $x^{-1} \circ x \circ \alpha$ answers my question. I am still confused with DoCarmo's exposition but with your hint, I think I am able to "reconstruct" the proof in a fashion that I can understand.

Comment: I do not blame you one bit for being bothered. I think his exposition and notation are horrid. ... My view (not that you care) is that at the undergraduate level, we should just work with parametrizations and not think of surfaces as abstract manifolds. If you're going to do the latter, then do everything coherently with a more rigorous underpinning than most undergraduates have. :)